# Showing validation message with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have the following field defined in my HTML code:

```
<label for="firstname" class="field prepend-icon"
      ng-class="{ 'state-error': submitted && helpForm.firstname.$error.required }">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required=""data-ng-model="firstname"
        class="gui-input" placeholder="First name...">
   <label for="firstname" class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
</label>
<span ng-show="{submitted && helpForm.firstname.$error.required}"
            class="state-error">Enter first name</span>
```

Here is the CSS class:

```
.smart-forms span.state-error {
   display: block !important;
   margin-top: 6px;
   padding: 0 3px;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-style: normal;
   line-height: normal;
   font-size: 0.85em;
   color: #DE888A;
}
```

The first part of the validation works well. That is, I am able to add the class 'state-error' to the Label upon validation error. I am using the condition:

```
ng-class="{ 'state-error': submitted && helpForm.firstname.$error.required }
```

and it works fine.

However, I am trying to use the same condition with 'ng-show' in order to HIDE the error message until there is a validation error, but I am not able to hide it. Here is the line of code that is responsible for it.

```
ng-show="{submitted && helpForm.firstname.$error.required}"
```

I also tried without the curly brackets like so:

```
ng-show="submitted && helpForm.firstname.$error.required"
```

In both cases the results were the same.

So the same condition works to add a class but doesn't work to show/hide element, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

remove {}?

ng-show="{submitted && helpForm.firstname.$error.required}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed the curly brackets but it didn't help. Actually I started without them.

Comment: you are right. Here is from angular doc.                                        Overriding .ng-hide

By default, the .ng-hide class will style the element with display:none!important. If you wish to change the hide behavior with ngShow/ngHide then this can be achieved by restating the styles for the .ng-hide class in CSS:

.ng-hide {
  /* this is just another form of hiding an element */
  display:block!important;
  position:absolute;
  top:-9999px;
  left:-9999px;
}

By default you don't need to override in CSS anything and the animations will work around the display style.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So the problem was in the CSS class.

I have defined:

```
display: block !important;
```

I removed this line and the problem was solved. Not sure, but i guess ng-show uses

```
'display:none'
```

and that my css class was overriding it. Anyway, it works now. So if you have the same problem, make sure  to check your CSS class.